# Can't boot my MacBook Pro with Fusion Drive

Tags: macos, disk-utility, core-storage, fusion-drive

I have checked almost all the "messed up the fusion drive" posts and don't find any close one to my situation, so I decide to ask a question and hope someone can help me, especially @klanomath :)

Here is what happened: I connected my mom's iPad with MacBook Pro 17" Late 2011 running OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 and doing backup then I go to sleep. Next day my mom just pulled her iPad out, later I get up and find the MacBook Pro just with white screen and can't do anything. I turned it off and restart it, the loading bar runs really slow and without finishing loading the laptop shut down automatically. Then I boot it with OS X Install USB and tried to use Disk Utility to fix the problem and it can't even read the disk. After which, I used the Terminal to get this information.

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Fusion                  127.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Fusion                  749.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +869.2 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 80F0349D-A7D9-456D-8880-FED244781EE5
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.1 GB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        7.7 GB     disk3s2
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk4
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7
/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8
/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk9
/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk10
/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk11
/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk12
/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk13
/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14
/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk15
/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk16
-bash-3.2# diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group A5384FEE-5734-426F-AE5D-FF37367CC18C
    =========================================================
    Name:         Fusion
    Status:       Online
    Size:         876988317696 B (877.0 GB)
    Free Space:   106496 B (106.5 KB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume FEAB1BB3-3316-40D7-9250-0D74E8A7BD41
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     127691702272 B (127.7 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 0481B354-BD46-4686-9811-48726EE6CF68
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     749296615424 B (749.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family FEEC011B-6438-4997-8749-715BDAA66892
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 80F0349D-A7D9-456D-8880-FED244781EE5
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          869211684864 B (869.2 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
-bash-3.2#
```

I don't have a Time Machine backup so if all the data could be recovered I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I was able to discover is to erase and format the drive. You can do that by following these steps:

1. Boot into [Internet Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).
2. Erase the drive using Disk Utility.
3. Reinstall OS X.

For more information read [How to reinstall OS X on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904), then click on [Erase a drive and reinstall OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#erase).

Comment: No another chance?

Comment: @Longtea As far as I can tell, no...but I'll up vote this question and hopefully it gets some more attention, just in case there is another solution.